# C compiler (X16) warning, but should be an error

Tags: c, embedded, xc16

```
 if (_1_HOUR < count_value < _2_HOUR) {...}
```

This code snippet generates a warning in MPLAB X (It apparently compiles with the XC16 compiler).  But I feel it should be an Error.  The correct code (IMHO) is:

```
 if ((count_value >_1_HOUR) && (count_value < _2_HOUR)) {...}
```

I looking for the C programming rule that covers this - does anyone know what that is?  Thanks.

Comment: In C `a < b < c` is equivalent to `(a < b) < c`, while `(a < b)` evaluates to either `0` or `1`. So by itself it is a valid expression, but is not doing what the same expression in math is doing. Your corrected code is.

Comment: the compiler is very nice to warn you :). it is a perfectly valid code. Bad but valid.

Comment: Mudge, "But I feel it should be an Error." Many compilers offer a "treat warnings as errors" option.

Comment: Thanks for all the good comments.  I should have remembered the "order of precedence" for operators, and that would have clued me in that this was a valid (even though unclear) statement.

Answer (score 4):

> looking for the C programming rule that covers this - does anyone know what that is?

Since you asked, the C 2018 rules that cover this grammatically are:

- 6.5.8 says a `relational-expression` may be `relational-expression < shift-expression`.
- Substituting this into its first operand, `relational-expression` may be a `relational-expression < relational-expession < shift-expression`.
- 6.5.8 also says a `relational-expression` may be `shift-expression`. So we can substitute this into the above twice to have `shift-expression < shift-expession < shift-expression`.
- 6.5.7 says a `shift-expression` may be `additive-expression`.
- 6.5.6 says an `additive-expression` may be `multiplicative-expression`.
- 6.5.5 says a `multiplicative-expression` may be `cast-expression`.
- 6.5.4 says a `cast-expression` may be `unary-expression`.
- 6.5.3 says a `unary-expression` may be `postfix-expression`.
- 6.5.2 says a `postfix-expression` may be `primary-expression`.
- 6.5.1 says a `primary-expression` may be `identifier` or `constant`.
- Therefore, a `relational-expression` may be `identifier < identifier < identifier`, which can be `_1_HOUR < count_value < _2_HOUR` (or, if any of those are macros that expand to constants or other expressions, similar rules apply).

The rules that cover this semantically are:

- 6.5.8 3 says both operands to `<` shall have real type (integers or floating-point numbers) or both shall be pointers (with certain restrictions). Presumably both `_1_HOUR` and `countvalue` have integer or floating-point type, satisfying the former.
- 6.5.8 6 says “… The result has type `int`.” Thus, when the operands of the second `<` are `_1_HOUR < countvalue` and `_2_HOUR` (also presumably integer or floating-point), they also satisfy 6.5.8 3.

Comment: I think you put too much effort to answer this very beginner question :) UV.

Comment: "_looking for the C programming rule that covers this_" - Ask, and it shall be given to you! :-) Got my vote too

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just came to the conclusion that in case Eric ever says something not found on the C standard, the C standard would be immediately modified accordingly. P.S.: +1 from me too.

Answer (score 2):

> I feel it should be an Error

Well, it's not. The code is perfectly valid and has defined behavior.

```
if (_1_HOUR < count_value < _2_HOUR) {...}
```

If the result of `1_HOUR < count_value` (which is `0` or `1` in arithmetic context) is less than `_2_HOUR` then `{...}`

Your X16 compiler probably supports these options that could help you though:
`-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`

I'm unsure if it also supports `-pedantic-errors`. The doc was a bit fuzzy.

`